# How to find the nearest neighbor in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

There are two array u and v.

u.shape = (N,d)
v.shape = (q,d)

I need to find, for every q, the nearest value's index for each d in u.

For example:

```
u = [[5,3],
     [3,4],
     [3,2],
     [8,7]] , shape (4,2)
v = [[1,3],
     [2,4]] , shape (2,2)
```

and I found many people said we can do that:

```
v = v.expand_dims(v,axis=1) # reshape to (2,1,2) for broadcast

result = np.argmin(abs(v-u),axis=1) # (u-v).shape = (2,4,2)
```

Of course it found the nearest value's index. But! when there are two nearest value, I need to take the "second" one's index.

In that case:

```
v-u = [[[-4,  0],
        [-2, -1],
        [-2,  1],
        [-7, -4]],

       [[-3,  1],
        [-1,  0],
        [-1,  2],
        [-6, -3]]])
```

along axis=1, there are two -2 in (u-v)[0,:,0] and two -1 in (u-v)[1,:,0]
If we directly use:

```
result = np.argmin(abs(v-u),axis=1)
```

result will be:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

It returns the indices corresponding to the first occurrence but I need the second one, i,e

```
array([[2, 0],
       [2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there can be at most 2 minimal values, you can retrieve indices of
the **last** minimum.

To do it:

- reverse *abs(v-u)* along axis 1,
- compute *argmin*, getting a "reversed_index" (actually the index in the
  reversed array),
- map back to "original" indices using *u.shape[0] - 1 - <reversed_index>*
  formula (in your case of 4 rows, *reversed index == 3* corresponds to
  *original index == 0*)

The whole code is:

```
u.shape[0] - 1 - np.argmin(abs(v-u)[:,::-1,:],axis=1)
```

**Other choice**, when there can be **more** than 2 min values, is to write
a specialized version of *argmin*, for an *1-D* input array, returning
the index of the **second** minimal value if there are more of them:

```
def argmin2(arr):
    ind = arr.argpartition(1)[:2]
    return ind[0] if arr[ind[0]] < arr[ind[1]] else ind[1]
```

and then apply it to *abs(v-u)* along axis *1*:

```
np.apply_along_axis(argmin2, 1, abs(v-u))
```